# Regular Expression for File Extension

Tags: html, regex

I'm wondering if there is a regular expression I can use to find file extensions using basic html.

Right now i have

```
<img src="images/pimage/{$item['item_id']}/small.jpg">
```

The problem is not all my images end in .jpg.

So I would like a regular expresion that can find all images that start with small and end in `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.JPG`, `.png`, `.gif`, etc... in both lower case and upper case.

Is there a simple regex I can put after "small" to find all matching files?

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but when I try any of the suggestions, the output show only the regex, and not the intended results.   here's my current code

```
        function print_item($item,$link_change){
        $acticon= ($item['active']==TREEMAN_ITEM_ACTIVE)? 'active.gif' : 'disabled.gif';
        $tmpl_act=($this->section->webmode)? "<td><img src=\"".ADMIN_IMG_PATH."icons/{$acticon}\"></td>" : "";
        $tmpl_date=date('Y-m-d H:i',$item['cdate']);
        $tmpl_added_by=$item['added_by'];
        $tmpl_modified_by=$item['modified_by'];
//      $tmpl_date_mod=date('Y-m-d H:i',$item['timestamp']);
        $tmpl_date_mod=$item['timestamp'];
        $res=<<<EOT
<td >{$item['item_id']}</td>
<td><a href="{$link_change}"</a><img src="/img/ucart/images/pimage/{$item['item_id']}/small.jpg" height="75" width="75"</td>
<td class="tb" width="50%"><a href="{$link_change}" title="Edit item">{$item['item_name']}</a></td>
<td>$tmpl_date</td>
<td>$tmpl_date_mod</td>
<td>$tmpl_added_by</td>
<td>$tmpl_modified_by</td>
$tmpl_act
EOT;
```

any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: For clarification, are you trying to return the filename `small-filename.jpg` or a regex to get the full file path e.g.  `images/pimage/27/small-filename.jpg` ?

Comment: All the file names are names small.   Some are small.jpg, some small.JPG, small.png, small.gif, etc...

Answer (score 7):

The regex to capture all images that begin with "small" and end in any extension that you've listed:

`/^small.*\.(jpe?g|gif|png|tiff)$/i`

Terms Explained:

`^` - starts with

`.*` - matches 0 or more of any character

`\.` - matches a period; `\` is an escape character that means the following character should be interpreted literally, which is necessary because the characters `.`, `?`, `+`, etc. have a meaning in regex otherwise.

`(a|b|c)` - matches anything contained inside the parentheses (example, matches if the next character is `a` or `b` or `c`)

`?` - signifies that the preceding character may appear zero or one time (example, `jpe?g` matches "jpeg" because it contains one 'e', and also matches "jpg" because the 'e' appears zero times in that position)

`$` - denotes end of pattern to be matched

`/your-regex-pattern/i` - case insensitive matches (upper and lowercase)

If you want to learn more about pattern matching in regex, check out this handy cheatsheet: http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Comment: Fails for any file containing a period other than the one before the extension (e.g., `small.heart.png` will fail even though it's a valid filename). Also, the end should be `(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|tiff)` (using parentheses, not brackets). Finally, you may be wise to specify `$` at the end of the pattern to make sure there are not any characters following the supposed file extension (e.g., your current patterns would succeed for something like: `small.jpg.php` or anything else that follows a valid image-extension).

Comment: @SpencerDoak Thanks for catching the '[]' vs '()'. As for the filename edge cases, I agree with you completely but I didn't account for those because OP gave us an idea what the filenames would look like.

Comment: One other thing, `jpg|jpeg` could be shortened to `jpe?g`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, this will help you?

```
/\.\w+$/
```

*(the dot sign and 1 (or more) word class characters at the end of input string)*

or

```
/\.[a-z]+$/i 
/\.[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

*(the dot sign and 1 (or more) letters at the end of input string)*

or

```
/\.[a-z]{1,4}$/i
/\.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}$/
```

*(the dot sign and 1 to 4 letters at the end of input string)*

Notice, that all options has a dot sign in output.
All regexps are case-insensitive since there is an `i`-flag.

---

Also, unfortunately, JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind, therefore regexp

```
/(?<=small\.)[a-z]+/i
```

*(1 or more letters after `small.` substring)*

won't work; but, I think, it would be the best regexp in this case.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page from www.Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html), case sensitivity and other similar matching-flags/options are usually implemented in the programming language rather than directly in the pattern itself. However, in the case that the language does not provide the option to pass in matching-flags/options, the RegEx info page linked above says options like case-insensitivity can be specified in the pattern.

To specify a pattern as being case-insensitive, you can specify `(?i)` as being the start of the case insensitive portion and `(?-i)` as being the end of the case-insensitive portion.

For your specific situation, this means the following RegEx pattern could be effective: `\.(?i)(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|ico|bmp|svg|tiff)(?-i)$` Obviously, you would want to modify this pattern to your needs to add or remove image file types.

In this pattern: `\.` denotes a literal period character (`.`); `(?i)` turns off case-sensitivity for all following parts; `(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|ico|bmp|svg|tiff)` denotes a list of options, meaning the file-extension must be one (and only one) of the options in the list; `(?-i)` turns on case-sensitivity; and `$` marks the end of the string, meaning there cannot be any characters following the file extension.

If the language you are using supports specifying matching-flags another way, then I would advise you to specify them in whatever way the language recommends; however, according to the RegEx information page I linked above, this is the proper way to specify them within the pattern (*which has the benefit of not making the entire pattern case-insensitive, if you decide to add more to the pattern*).

**EDIT**: as a warning, it looks like Javascript does not support turning case sensitivity on and off within the pattern itself (using `(?i)` and `(?-i)`). So, if you're working with Javascript you would have to work around that by either setting `/i` as a flag at the end of your expression or using a pattern such as the following: `\.([pP][nN][gG]|[jJ][pP][eE]?[gG]|[gG][iI][fF]|[iI][cC][oO]|[tT][iI][fF]{1,2})$`. In this pattern, every letter in the extension is specified in both upper-and-lower-case. This allows the pattern to match a file extension no matter what case it is written in, while still allowing the rest of the expression to be case sensitive.